# Numpy casts to python float when dividing by a large integer, is this a bug?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, types, casting

Here is a minimal code example:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array(1e-35, dtype=np.double)
y = int(1e19)
print( type(x/y) )

y = int(1e20)
print( type(x/y) )
```

On my machine in the former case it prints `numpy.float64`, and in the latter case it prints `float`. I imagine the specific numbers will vary on different machines, but the point is that for small ints the division preserves type, while for large ints the type is cast to a Python float. I would like to know whether this is a bug in Numpy or not, and whether there are any solutions besides manually casting everything to be a double.

It seems harmless, but when I try to write a `ufunc` and the cast only happens on certain elements of an array, the return type becomes `object`, and the program throws a "could not be coerced to provided output parameter" error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output type change because `int(1e19)` can be safely casted to an `np.int64` while `int(1e20)` cannot fit in an `np.int64` and thus cannot be safely casted (you can check that with `y.bit_length()`). As a result, `y` is first kept as pure-Python object (a variable-sized integer), then Python cast it to a pure-Python float object so the result is a also pure-Python float object too. This happens because Numpy try to apply its own semantics rules based on native types. When it cannot use them (due to unsafe/impossible casts), **the fallback pure-Python object-based semantics is applied** resulting in pure-Python objects. Still, this appear to be a [known issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/16689). You can check related issues and discuss with Numpy developers on GitHub for more information.

I think the best strategy is not to rely on this behaviour. Indeed, when a float-like value is multiplied by a huge integer, the huge integer will always be casted to a float-like value first (because of semantics rules). This cast likely introduces a loss of precision as well as the following multiplication. Thus, I think this is better to cast the huge integer yourself to keep in mind that the integer value may not be perfectly represented.